# why wordpress custom rest api route only work for 'GET'

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I create a most simple rest api route

```
   public static function register_my_route(){
    register_rest_route( 'vender/v1','test',array(
        'method' => 'POST',
        'callback' => function(){return 1;}
    ));
}

add_action( 'rest_api_init', array( __CLASS__, 'register_my_route' ) );
```

I use postman to test it, always return   "code": "rest_no_route", 404, but if I change it to method => GET, it works

Answer (score -1):

Try to use the [WP_REST_Server](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_rest_server/) constants and also define the permissions for your declaration.

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function() {
    register_rest_route( 'vender/v1', '/test', array(
        'methods'             => WP_REST_Server::CREATEABLE,
        'callback'            => function() { return 'works'; },
        'permission_callback' => function() { if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_posts' ) ) { return false; } return true; },
    ) );
} );
```

Hope this helps!